# Correctly parse a DynamoDB AttributeValue

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have the following method:

```
public static object GetValueFromAttributeValue(AttributeValue value)
{
    if(value == null) return null;
    if(value.N != null) return Convert.ToInt64(value.N); //long
    if(value.B != null) return value.B; //MemoryStream
    if(value.S != null) return value.S; //string
    if(value.SS != null) return value.SS; //List<string>
    if(value.BS != null) return value.BS; //List<MemoryStream>
    if(value.NS != null) return value.NS.Select(v => Convert.ToInt64(v)).ToList(); //List<long>
    if(value.IsLSet && value.L != null) return value.L.Select(v => GetValueFromAttributeValue(v)).ToList(); //List<object>
    if(value.IsMSet && value.M != null) return value.M.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => GetValueFromAttributeValue(i.Value)); //Dictionary<string, object>
    if(value.IsBOOLSet) return value.BOOL; //bool
    return null;
}
```

The problem here is that `AttributeValue.SS`, `AttributeValue.BS` and `AttributeValue.NS` are never null, even if the `AttributeValue` object itself is not mapped to any list, it just returns an empty list.

So, all the conditions below those three are never reached nor met, because `(value.SS != null)` is always true.

`AttributeValue` does not define a property like `IsSSet` or something similar so I can know if the value is **in fact** an `SS`, `BS` or `NS`.

You can see that this helper property exists for other attribute value types, such as `L`, `M` and `BOOL`.

If the attribute value corresponds to a string type, then `S != null`, but also `SS != null`, `BS != null` and `NS != null`.

If the attribute value corresponds to a string set for example, then `SS != null`, `BS != null`, `NS != null`.

As you can see, I have no way to determine if a value corresponds to any of the three types. I have no way to identify these attribute values.

Comment: Why not just `SS.Count > 0` to determine if the list has something in it?

Comment: @MikeHixson what if the AttributeValue contains a list with size 0? It will not be parsed then

Comment: SS, BS, and NS values are sets that cannot be empty, so a check `SS.Count > 0` is appropriate.